# Get email alerts of website visitors Location

Tags: geolocation

I want to get email alert of my website visitors location (City, Region, Country, Postal Code), who visit my website. By using PHP/Javascript. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can install [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) on your site (it's free), you can define custom reports to be sent by mail, for example, daily visitors by location.